# how can i print reports from browser in php

Tags: php, mysql, printing

I have a report say,

**Sno   Address   Name   Age**

when users click on Print button, they should be able to print the respective report

Can anyone help me how can i handle this in php, as i generate this report in php

I get all the info from table(MySql)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you already have the PHP code which generates the report?

Comment: Server-side php cannot access the printer attached to the client's computer. It's not very much php/mysql related as you would have the problems with jsp/oracle or rubyonrails/postgres.

Comment: yeah, i already have the php code which generates the dynamic data from MySql and gives me the report, but i'm not able to give the printout of this report ?

Answer (score 3):

[CSS Printing](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_reference.asp#print) can be pretty good, but isn't the most reliable. An alternative is to look at generating PDF files from PHP. Take a look at the [FPDF library](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: Thanq, ur answer gave me an clue
I'm generating the Excel/PDF docs and users can take prints from those docs

Thanx a lot

Answer (score 2):

This is a function of the browser, not any server-side code. However, you can provide a button (which you code in the HTML output) which will print the page when clicked. Incidentally, depending on the browser configuration, it may also print the button.

```
<input type="button" onClick="window.print()" value="Print The Report"/>
```

Comment: window.print() -> will print the whole page right

Lets say my webpage is a 2 column layout and and in the second column i'm generating the report

Is there a way i give print, only the desired layoout

Answer (score 1):

I would not call this a PHP issue per se, as the solution is very easy through the use of some CSS rules.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

That should contain all you need to know, specifically the "print" media type. :)

Edit: This should have been a response to the comment above where the issue was clarified a bit.